# Adding new indexes and facet fields to KOHA

Tags: indexing

I use the following procedures from https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/How_to_add_new_zebra_index and https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Understanding_Zebra_indexing, but get no facet shown:

/etc/koha/zebradb/marc_defs/marc21/biblios/biblio-koha-indexdefs.xml:

```
<index_data_field xmlns="http://www.koha-community.org/schemas/index-defs" tag="380" subfields="a">
 <target_index>FormOfWork:w</target_index>
</index_data_field>
```

/etc/koha/zebradb/biblios/etc/bib1.att:

```
att 10000    FormOfWork
```

/etc/koha/zebradb/ccl.properties:

```
FormOfWork 1=10000
```

lib/C4/Koha.pm, in sub getFacets, (non-unimarc):

```
{
            idx   => 'FormOfWork',
            label => 'FormOfWork',
            tags  => [ qw/ 380a / ],
            sep   => '--',
},
```

opac/htdocs/opac-tmpl/bootstrap//includes/opac-facets.inc, after  [% FOREACH facets_loo IN facets_loop %]:

```
[% IF facets_loo.type_label_FormOfWork %]<h5 id="facet-FormOfWork">Form of work</h5>[% END %]
```

lib/C4/Search.pm, in sub getIndexesn my @indexes added:

```
'FormOfWork',
```

Running:

```
xsltproc /etc/koha/zebradb/xsl/koha-indexdefs-to-zebra.xsl /etc/koha/zebradb/marc_defs/marc21/biblios/    biblio-koha-indexdefs.xml >/etc/koha/zebradb/marc_defs/marc21/biblios/biblio-zebra-indexdefs.xsl
koha-rebuild-zebra -b -f -v library
koha-restart-zebra
```

Example MARC21 record (none, one or more in same record; existing in multiple records):

```
380$a Play
380$a Screenplay
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,